# C# proplem with 32bit executable

Tags: c#, winforms, odbc

I wrote this code using Visual Studio 2015:

```
static string strconnect = "Dsn=mx86";
static public string strDoc_key = "";
static public bool bPicFounded = false;
OdbcDataAdapter dr = new OdbcDataAdapter();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Thread thread = null;
static public OdbcConnection dataConnection = new OdbcConnection(strconnect);
static public string strInitialDirectory = "";

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
        if (dataConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            dataConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.Close(); }));
    }
    try
    {
       // this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
       // {

            DataTable mydt = new DataTable();
            using (OdbcCommand ord = new OdbcCommand("", dataConnection))
            {
                ord.CommandText = "SELECT `AnläggningsNr` GroupID ,`Beskrivning` GroupName  from `Utrustningar` " +
                                  "WHERE (((`NivåUpp`)='TOP') AND ((`Enhet`)='00'))";

                mydt.Load(ord.ExecuteReader());

                cboGroups.SelectedIndexChanged -= cboGroups_SelectedIndexChanged;

                if (mydt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    cboGroups.ValueMember = "GroupID";
                    cboGroups.DisplayMember = "GroupName";

                    cboGroups.DataSource = mydt.DefaultView;

                    cboGroups.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    cboGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
                }

                cboGroups.SelectedIndexChanged += cboGroups_SelectedIndexChanged;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("a)Message is: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

When I make x86 build, the combobox is filled with `system.data.datarowview` but when I make x64 build, it works fine.

What could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that your combobox is filled with strings, each of which is simply "System.Data.DataRowView"? Or do you mean something else? Have you stepped through your code to see what your data looks like exactly?

Comment: yes when i make x86 build combo box filled with string "System.Data.DataRowView" when imake x64 build combo box filled with true data ?

Answer (score 0):

When I replace
Display member value from 
cboGroups.DisplayMember = "GroupName";
To
cboGroups.DisplayMember = mydt.columns[1].columnname
And make the same with value member it works good and give me the expected results
So when I try to debug to know the difference between the two expressions
I notice that
The string "GroubName" come with null terminated character like "GroubName\0" so mydt.columns[1].column name give the right column name with null terminated character
This is what I noticed 
Ithink the proplem in odbc driver which give me this type of errors